# "Как-то" — это два слова или одно?

Tags: морфология

Слово или слова? "Как-то" — это два слова или одно?

Скажу проще, как и то разные слова (т.е. два отдельных слова)? Или одно целое (т.е. одно слово)?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Как-то** - местоименное наречие, где "то" - суффикс с дефисным написанием. Это одно слово. Здесь **как-то** неуютно.

2) **Как то** (то есть, а именно) - составной союз (перед перечислением) состоит из двух слов. Гости говорили о многих приятных и полезных вещах, **как то:** о природе, о собаках, о чепчиках, о жеребцах.

Comment: "то" - не суффикс, а частица.

Comment: Будьте внимательнее при постановке минусов, пользуйтесь справочной литературой. В Грамматике 80 сказано, что неопределенные местоимения образуются с помощью постфикса ТО. Возможно, Вам будет также интересна такая информация: "Смысловую частицу -то  надо отличать от словообразующего постфикса -то , выступающего как средство образования неопределённых местоимений и наречий: какой-то, куда-то  (постфикс) — Я-то знаю, куда надо идти  (частица)." http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=c8641dbf-8500-479b-b1ba-6176fcf59d35

Comment: Непременно учту ваши пожелания и поставлю вам минус за постфикс, который вы назвали суффиксом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не ставьте, уж очень Вы суровы к другим,  в отличие от себя. Постфикс  ТО - это всё же словообразовательный элемент, от суффикса отличается позицией, но не функцией, а вот Вам совсем не простительно утверждать, что как-то - это два слова.

Comment: Ну знаете, если Вы называете "Академической грамматикой" непонятно что, непонятно кем и непонятно зачем написанное на непонятно каком сайте... Понимаете, штука вся в том, что от того, что частицу "то" назвали "постфиксом" она не перестала быть частицей. Любое слово есть какая-то часть речи. Частица - часть речи. Постфикс - нет. Поэтому, если "куда" и "то" - два слова, то "то" прежде всего именно частица, а все остальное - потом. Что там хотели по вашей ссылке сказать - это отдельный разговор.

Comment: Да Вы Грамматику-то тоже откройте, почитайте,  сведения приведены не только с сайта. Частица - это название грамматического класса,  при этом частицы могут выполнять разные функции,  том числе словообразовательную, постфикс - это функция частицы. Так "как-то" одно слово или два, дайте всё-таки окончательный ответ.

Comment: Sergey, если уж Вы ссылаетесь на реальную грамматику, давайте реальные ссылки, а не изложение своих непричесанных мыслей.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35963/discussion-between-behemothus-and-sergey).

Comment: Я опасаюсь, что в чате Вы сразу перейдете на ненормативную лексику. Я, если позволите, только приведу "НЕПРИЧЕСАННУЮ ЦИТАТУ" из Краткой русской грамматики под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина (1990г, 2-е изд.):  "Неопределенные местоимения образуются от вопросительных с помощью приставок не- и кое-, постфиксов -то-, -либо-, -нибудь".

Answer (score 0):

Орфографически это одно слово, слова написанные через дефис трактуются как одно, отсюда и понимание дефиса как знака орфографического, а не пунктуационного. Иная трактовка потребовала бы слишком много оговорок разного рода рои формулировках правил.

А вот грамматически это два слова, одно из которых - местоименное наречие, второе - частица.

Вам надо определиться, в рамках какой сферы вы рассматриваете это сочетание - грамматической или орфографической. Предполагаю, что скорее всего первой, грамматической, ибо с орфография тут большого интереса не представляет и никаких вопросов обычно не порождает. Так что в первом приближении можете считать, что слова два.

(+)===========

Я внес правку, поскольку по рассеянности назвал было "как" местоимением, хотя здесь это местоименное **наречие**. Ошибка чисто механическая, я, когда писал, думал о другом слове ("кто-то"). Ни на что больше не влияет, всё сказанное - в силе.